# SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have function

```
function bgSetDisableOverlappedContent(CAA: BOOL; var ErrorCode: DWORD; ErrorText: string): Boolean;  
begin
  errorCode := ERROR_SUCCESS;
  ErrorText := '';  
  if not GetOSVersion >= 60 then
    Exit;
  Result := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, @CAA, 0);
  if not Result then
  begin
    ErrorCode := GetLastError;
    ErrorText := GetErrorText(ErrorCode);
  end;
end;
```

and call it exactly

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CAA: BOOL;
  OS: TUsableInOS;
  ErrorCode: DWORD;
  ErrorText: string;
begin
  CAA := False;
  if bgSetDisableOverlappedContent(CAA, ErrorCode, ErrorText) then
    ShowMessage('Success');
end;
```

But, when I inspect again with next code

```
function bgGetDisableOverlappedContent(var CAA: BOOL; OS: TUsableInOS; ErrorCode: DWORD; ErrorText: string): Boolean;
begin
  errorCode := ERROR_SUCCESS;
  ErrorText := '';
  os := tosVistaUp;   
  if not GetOSVersion >= 60 then
    Exit;   
  Result := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, @CAA, 0);   
  if not Result then
  begin
    ErrorCode := GetLastError;
    ErrorText := GetErrorText(ErrorCode);
  end;
end;
function GetOSVersion: Integer;
var
  OSVersionInfo : TOSVersionInfo;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  FillChar(OsVersionInfo, Sizeof(OsVersionInfo), 0);
  OSVersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(OSVersionInfo);
  if GetVersionEx(OSVersionInfo) then
  begin
    if OSVersionInfo.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
    begin
      if (OsVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 5) and ((OsVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion = 0)) then
         Result:= 50; //2000
      if (OsVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 5) and ((OsVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion = 1)) then
         Result:= 51; //XP
      if (OsVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 5) and ((OsVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion = 2)) then
         Result:= 52; //2003, 2003 R2
      if (OsVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 6) and ((OsVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion = 0)) then
         Result:= 60; //Vista, Windows Server 2008
      if (OsVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 6) and ((OsVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion = 1)) then
         Result:= 61; //Server 2008 R2, 7
    end;
  end;
end;
```

result for CAA is again True, even I exactly set  CAA := False;
I am working on Win 7. and Result of Result := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, @CAA, 0); is True, but SPI_GETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT returns True for CAA, even in step before it exactly was set as False.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CAA: BOOL;
  OS: TUsableInOS;
  ErrorCode: DWORD;
  ErrorText: string;
  Res: Bool;
begin
  CAA := False;
{  if bgSetDisableOverlappedContent(CAA, ErrorCode, ErrorText) then
    ShowMessage('Success'); }
  Res := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT,
                                 0,
                                 @CAA,
                                 0);

  Res := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT,
                                 0,
                                 @CAA,
                                 0);
  if Caa then
    ShowMessage('True')
  else
    ShowMessage('False');
end;
```

CAA is True.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance
Bojan

Comment: @paulsm4 That code is bogus, but there are other problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is that when passing `SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT` you are meant to pass a `BOOL` variable, but you are passing a pointer to a `BOOL`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx#SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT) says:

> The pvParam parameter is a BOOL variable. Set pvParam to TRUE to disable overlapped content, or FALSE to enable overlapped content.

Which means that your code to set the property needs to be like this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, Pointer(CAA), 0)
```

---

Your `GetOSVersion` is a disaster. Sorry to sound harsh! It returns `0` for Windows 8 and later. And your code has problems with operator precedence. You write:

```
if not GetOSVersion >= 60 then
```

and operator precedence means that is interpreted as

```
if (not GetOSVersion) >= 60 then
```

Since `GetOSVersion` returns a signed value, `(not GetOSVersion) >= 60` evaluates to `False` irrespective of windows version. That's because `not GetOSVersion` is always <= `0`.

You want logical negation rather than bitwise negation. So you should write

```
if not (GetOSVersion >= 60) then
```

or equivalently

```
if GetOSVersion < 60 then
```

In reality there is a built in function to do this. It's called `CheckWin32Version`. Call it like this:

```
if not CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  exit;
```

---

The rest of your function is a bit of a mess though. You pass `ErrorText` by value and then assign to it. Presumably you are intending the caller to receive that value. Which won't happen unless you passed by `var`.

Personally I'd write your procedure like this:

```
procedure bgSetDisableOverlappedContent(CAA: BOOL);
begin
  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    if not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, Pointer(CAA), 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

I think it's better to convert an error in `SystemParametersInfo` to an exception since it's an exceptional circumstance. I defy you to actually generate a failure of that call to `SystemParametersInfo`. In which case there's no point building an error code returning mechanism for something that simply will not happen. Check for errors and convert to a runtime exception. This makes the calling code so much simpler.

Your button click handler can be much simpler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bgSetDisableOverlappedContent(False);
end;
```

And the getter function is also much more complex than necessary. I'd have it like this:

```
function bgGetDisableOverlappedContent: Boolean;
var
  CAA: BOOL;
begin
  if not CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    Result := False;//or True, I don't know, you decide
    exit;
  end;
  if not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, @CAA, 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := CAA;
end;
```